# How to create a "silent" MySQL docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, bash, images, mysql

How can I [create](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12317/23443) a `MySQL` docker container as below in the background:

```
root:~# 
root:~# docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass --name sql-db -p 3306:3306 mysql &
[1] 137878
root:~# 2020-09-01 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-09-01 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-09-01 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-09-01 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-09-01T08:25:52.978020Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as process 42
2020-09-01T08:25:52.986993Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

root:~# 
root:~# 2020-09-01T08:26:03.346159Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-01T08:26:29.360246Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

root:~# 
root:~# 2020-09-01 08:27:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2020-09-01 08:27:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2020-09-01T08:27:35.640682Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 89
2020-09-01T08:27:35.782142Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-01T08:27:37.207138Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-01T08:27:37.562152Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-01T08:27:38.036662Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-01T08:27:38.036911Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-01T08:27:38.071799Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-01T08:27:38.105387Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-09-01 08:27:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

2020-09-01 08:27:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2020-09-01T08:27:51.591046Z 10 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21).
2020-09-01T08:28:09.444982Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-09-01 08:28:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2020-09-01 08:28:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2020-09-01T08:28:10.181619Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1
2020-09-01T08:28:10.297757Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-09-01T08:28:11.863493Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-09-01T08:28:12.702126Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2020-09-01T08:28:14.231915Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-09-01T08:28:14.232156Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-09-01T08:28:14.470976Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-09-01T08:28:14.498996Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

root:~# 
root:~# 
root:~# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
8a63d8b9d9c2        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   sql-db
root:~# 
root:~# docker exec -it 8a63d8b9d9c2 bash
root@8a63d8b9d9c2:/# 
root@8a63d8b9d9c2:/#
```

so that it's a bit less spammy?

(Yes, I could just switch to another terminal, using something like `tmux`, or route output to `/dev/null` of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the container in detached mode by passing `-d` or `--detach` with the run command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground